# jQuery Using .trigger() with key values

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble grasping how to use jquery .trigger().  I'm simply looping around checkboxes and finding which checkboxes have been checked. I am then trying to map those values to a key value pair. If I log paymentValue and paymentName I get the correct output which would be something like: **cash** and **true** so I want something like **cash : true** in my key value.
Except when I try to run this code I get a **paymentName is not defined error**

```
var filterPayment = $('input[name="filter-payment"]:checked');
var paymentObj = {};         

$(document).bind("updateFilters", function() {
    filterPayment.each( function () {
       var paymentValue = paymentObj[this.value];
       paymentValue = this.checked;   

       var paymentName = userObj[this.name];
       paymentName = this.value;             
    });
});

$(document).trigger('updateFilters', {
    paymentValue : paymentName
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the variable `paymentName` is not declared... it is declared in the local scope of the `each` callback

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something how would you declare it outside of the each callback? If I put it above the each callback as just var paymentName I still get the same error. Can you include an example I learn better by seeing some code.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? are you trying to fire the `updateFilters` event for each `input[name="filter-payment"]:checked` element?

Comment: Your correct I'm trying to fire updateFilters every time there is a checkbox that is checked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var filterPayment = $('input[name="filter-payment"]');
var paymentObj = {};
var userObj = {};

//listern to the change event
filterPayment.change(function () {
    var paymentValue = paymentObj[this.value];
    paymentValue = this.checked;

    var paymentName = userObj[this.name];
    paymentName = this.value;

    //create a parameter object, since the key is dynamic need to use bracket notation to assign the value
    var param = {};
    param[paymentValue] = paymentName;

    $(document).trigger('updateFilters', param);
}).filter(':checked').change()

$(document).bind("updateFilters", function () {
    alert('filter updated')
});
```